# Запись и чтение JSON ( через GSON )

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, пытался сделать запись и чтение JSON,однако не вышло ( корректно уж точно );

Как я записываю:

```
/// Это выполним после загрузки и установки
        ModModelClass MMC = new ModModelClass(id, name, category, filesize, null);
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/mods_installed_db.json", true)) {
            writer.write(gson.toJson(MMC) + "\n");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

P.S Код выше так же производит неверную запись, дело в том, что после добавления 2-ой строки и далее, структура становится невалидной.

Хотелось бы при записи записывать не просто строку JSON-а, а подобную структуру:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Текст",
"author": "Автор",
"downloadlink": "Ссылка",
"status": 1,
"previewimgurl": "Ссылка",
"rating": 0,
"workshoplink": "Ссылка",
"description": "Текст",
"mindescript": "Мин деск",
"modsize": 60.1
```

},

Как я пытался искать и читать ( по сути тут, я хотел просканировать весь JSON для сверки id из его строки, с переменной id из моего кода, если id совпадают, значит ресурс устаовлен, если нет, то наоборот, но получилось весьма топорно (( и ниего увы не заработало )))

```
Gson g = new Gson();
    FileReader x = null;
    try {
        x = new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/mods_installed_db.json");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader varRead = new BufferedReader(x);
    JSONParserModel jsm = g.fromJson(varRead, JSONParserModel.class);
    String jsid = jsm.id;
    if(jsid == id) {
        StatInfiusBool = true;
        statusinfo = "Установлен";
    }
    else{
        StatInfiusBool = false;
        statusinfo = "Не установлен";
    }
```

Comment: Вы хотите записать в один файл несколько объектов, но не все разом, а дописывать по одному? Это проблематично - проще собрать их в список/массив и записать разом. Читать также в список/массив и дальше работать как обычно работают с массивами.

Comment: Скорее да, чем нет, данный код выполняется при открытие элемента в recyclerview в нём и содержатся эти данные, которые читаются и записываются при открытии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь добиться, что Json был читабельным, а не слитной строкой по умолчанию. На то существует способ *pretty print*:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
writer.write(gson.toJson(MMC));
writer.flush();
```

Comment: Да, но это не одна проблема, а также чтение, касательно записи... GJSON не хочет нормально записывать, дело в том, что все файлы JSON не валидны, по двум причинам: После записи данных не ставится ,  ( что проблема ), и самое печальное, не ставятся символы ( [ и ] в начале и конце, что полностью убирает возможность нормального чтения даже в коде ), как быть с этим, не подскажете ?

Comment: Чтобы записалось как вы хотите нужно собрать все объекты в массив и записать этот массив, либо добавлять разделители `[],` самому. Но это вам не поможет читать их по-одному - нужно будет вычитать весь массив разом, либо опять же вручную искать разделители, вычитывать кусок в строку и уже  её конвертировать в объект. По-хорошему, если у вас много таких объектов и нужен поиск, фильтрация, сортировка среди них по разным свойствам, то стоит освоить Room Database

Comment: woesss, можно пример подобного кода?